# Proof of $n!\geq2^{n-1}$ by mathematical induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, induction

I am trying to make a proof

$$n!\geq2^{n-1}\;\;\forall \;n\in N$$

Here's what I've done!

$ \text{When}\;\; n=1,\;\; 2^{0}\leq 1!$,

$ \text{when}\;\; n=2,\;\; 2^{1}\leq 2!$,

$ \text{when}\;\; n=3,\;\; 2^{2}\leq 3!$,

$\vdots$

Assume it is true for $n=k$, then

$$2^{k-1}\leq k!$$.

Now, we want to prove for $n=k+1$.

I got stuck at this point. I need help! Thanks!

Comment: you need to show that $2^{k-1} \le k! \implies 2^k \le (k+1)!$ which will be true if $2 \le k+1$

Comment: What happens if you multiply both sides by $2$?  What happens if you multiply both sides by $k+1$?  Which is bigger $2$ or $k+1$?

Comment: Thanks to you both! I've got it!

Comment: The symbol $P(n)$ usually denotes a formula with $n$ being a free variable. Moreover, $2^{n-1}$ is too short, so we should not create a symbol $P(n)$ to denote it.

Comment: @  Danny Pak-Keung Chan: I accept that!

Comment: @ @ Danny Pak-Keung Chan: I have edited it for other other readers' sake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then for $n = k+1$, we have
$$2^k = 2\cdot2^{k-1} \le 2 \cdot k!\ \text{ by inductive argument}$$
From here, it is easy to see that $2\cdot k! \le (k+1)k! = (k+1)!$

Comment: I am very grateful for your help!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
(k+1)! &= k!(k+1) \\
&\ge2^{k-1}(k+1)
\end{align}

Can you complete it?

Comment: Thanks, I even got the solution immediately I posted it. I confirmed with yours! You are very correct! I have completed it!

Answer (score 3):

You're off by $1$ in your basis observations; you should have, instead, the following:

$$
1! \geq 2^0 \\
2! \geq 2^1 \\
3! \geq 2^2
$$

For the induction step, you should be thinking like this:

$$
2^k = 2 \times 2^{k-1} \leq \cdots
$$

Can you complete that line?

---

P.S.  Siong Thye Goh's answer gives the other half... :-)

Answer (score 3):

If $n=1$, we have $1!=1\ge 1= 2^0$.

Suppose that $n!\ge 2^{n-1}$ for some $n\ge1$.

Then $$(n+1)! = (n+1)\cdot n! \ge 2\cdot n! \ge 2\cdot 2^{n-1} = 2^n$$

So, by induction, $n!\ge 2^{n-1}$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.